# how to get predis data with offset and limit?

Tags: php, redis, predis

i stored my data as encoded data in redis using predis hset library.
so the data is stored in one of the db in a hash name like e.g myHash

```
field = integer
value = encoded data..
```

e.g

```
1    {'pk_id':1,'name' : 'test1'}
2    {'pk_id':2,'name' : 'test2'}
3    {'pk_id':3,'name' : 'test3'}
...and so on...
```

there were like 400k+ rows of integer field with their encoded data.
is there a way to pull these datas with offset and limit ?
because if i do e.g

```
$predisObj->hgetall('myHash');
```

it pulls out everything and the browser crashes because of too many data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

predis shares the command list with redis as it is a php interface for redis store. Therefore you can use the standard redis commands to fulfill your needs:

The best way to achieve what you want is [SCAN command](https://redis.io/commands/scan) 
From predis [documentation](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.0/examples/redis_collections_iterators.php):

```
// === Keyspace iterator based on SCAN ===
echo 'Scan the keyspace matching only our prefixed keys:', PHP_EOL;
foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($client, 'predis:*') as $key) {
    echo " - $key", PHP_EOL;
}
```

This command will return an iterator thus the memory issues will not be of importance anymore.

Comment: what is the value of that $client var in your code snippet ? is it supposed to be my predis object ?, and is that 'predis:*'  parameter supposed to be that way? or i had to change it with my hash name ?

Comment: the code is taken from the documentation link. thus: `$client = new Predis\Client($single_server, array('profile' => '2.8'));` `predis:*` is supposed to be your query. You can find out more in (https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.1.1/examples/redis_collections_iterators.php#L43-L47)

Comment: when I pass ($client, 'myHash')   I get  this message `Message: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` ....what type was it looking for ? , my data in that redis db is field and encoded data

Comment: It seems it is a data/operation type mismatch. I haven't encountered such error before, but a quick look on the internet gave me this: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2864#issuecomment-156057011 Maybe it can help you from here.

Comment: great, I used the `type myHash` in the command line, and it's a hash..i used the HashKey iterator...the problem now is, it's still crashing..where should I pass the offset and limit..to avoid to much data?